# Keepass2 failed installation during upgrade from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, apt, 16.04, upgrade, keepass

I upgraded my laptop from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS. The keepass2 package could not be installed during the upgrade. So I skipped it to have the computer working again.

Today I tried to install keepass2, now using apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install keepass2
```

but I get the following error message:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/k/keepass2/keepass2_2.32+dfsg-1_all.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
```

I also tried to download the package using firefox directly from
http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/all/keepass2/download so I could install it using dpkg, but the package seems to have some problem.
Firefox opens a pop up window with the error message:

> /tmp/mozilla_srv0/44Gr76dJ.deb.part could not be saved, because the source file could not be read.

When downloading the file with wget and checking its md5sum signature the results is not the expected correct one.

```
$ wget http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/k/keepass2/keepass2_2.32+dfsg-1_all.deb
$ md5sum keepass2_2.32+dfsg-1_all.deb
9d21dfe6ff3374e05b84615abc0aa7f3  keepass2_2.32+dfsg-1_all.deb
```

Do you know how to install this package correctly?

Answer (score 1):

That's a strange one, but I've seen similar errors before from package files that had their download corrupted by a sketchy wifi connection on my end.

First I'd do a complete removal of the failed install using

```
sudo apt-get purge keepass*
```

and clean out your local repository with

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

Then try downloading the .deb file again from http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/k/keepass2/ (we're up to version 2.34 now; if you haven't got it working yet maybe you'll have more luck with the newest version ;) and run it with Ubuntu's software manager.

If that doesn't work, run another purge and clean on keepass2, then try the [.deb package download from debian.org](https://packages.debian.org/sid/all/keepass2/download) by installing it as you normally would.

If *that* doesn't work, jtaylor's PPA might. Run another purge and clean, then run

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jtaylor/keepass
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install keepass2
```

and see how that works out.

Answer (score 1):

[This guide](https://sysads.co.uk/2017/03/01/install-keepass-on-ubuntu-linux/) seems to be working for me.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:jtaylor/keepass
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install keepass2
```

Comment: same as the other answer